# Crash while calling NewStringUTF()

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, java-native-interface

I'm writing a JNI to call a C++ code from Java. it has been crashed when I used *NewStringUTF()* . Here is my code:

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "The value of 3 is %d", 3);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "The value of id is %s", id.c_str());

jstring jsId = m_env->NewStringUTF(id.c_str());// CODE CRASHES HERE

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "The value of 4 is %d", 4);
```

And output is :

```
V/myapplication ( 4930): The value of 3 is 3
V/myapplication( 4930): The value of id is 999999999999@example.example.net
F/art     ( 4930): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: thread Thread[12,tid=5100,Native,Thread*=0xa1033400,peer=0x12c5b0e0,"QtThread"] using JNIEnv* from thread Thread[17,tid=5359,Runnable,Thread*=0xb4e0ac00,peer=0x12e37080,"Thread-161252"]
F/art     ( 4930): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     in call to NewStringUTF
F/art     ( 4930): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     from void
```

It was crashed while I debugging on Android 5 but it's ok with lower version.
any suggestion?

EDITED: I changed m_env. here is my code :

```
JNIEnv *env = NULL;
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "The value of 3 is %d", 3);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "The value of jid is %s", jid.c_str());

jstring jsJid = env->NewStringUTF(jid.c_str());
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "The value of 4 is %d", 4);
```

and output is :

```
F/libc    (28181): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 28354 (QtThread)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JNIEnv` objects are to be used only by the specific thread requested the pointer.  In this case it seems like your `QtThread` stored the `m_env` pointer, but now it's being used by a new unnamed thread (`Thread-161252`).

Take a look at the [Android JNI Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) page for more information.

Comment: Just to expand on this answer, earlier versions of Android JVM were much less sensitive to inaccuracy of JNI conventions.

Comment: Now you're not setting your `JNIEnv` to anything and you're getting dereferencing null...   does your C method not have a `JNIEnv` object passed in as the first parameter (like in this example: http://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni.html#ci)?